# JetBrains Rider targets 4.5 framework and no option to switch to 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, rider

Basically, when trying to add NuGet package which is not supporting older frameworks getting the error.

However in project configuration only 4.5 is available.

During the project creation no option to select the target is present.

Is there any way to configure it properly?

Comment: If you have visual studio installed try change target framework there. There is a tag `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>` in csproj file. Try edit it to 4.7 and see if it works.

Comment: Well, that did the trick, but now IDE is showing the pop-up that 4.7 Dev Pack is missing. Apparently one from VS is not shareable... And that is not and obvious solution. :(

Comment: Try to install it https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168. Maybe that's why it was not available in Rider.

Comment: Yeah, thats what did the trick. But then I had to switch to it from xml config, not from Rider itself =(

Answer (score 8):

I haven't found out how to set up .NET framework globally but here is a convenient way:
[image]