# How to change .NET Framework in Rider IDE?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version, rider

In Rider IDE, I am trying to create a new solution:

[image]

But I'm unable to change the .NET Framework as the dropdown is disabled. How can I change the version? I have installed .NET Framework 3.5, 4.5, 4.6.

Comment: I think you can change it in your project properties.

Comment: @Sankar It will be for each project? I can't just make an entire solution for specific version?

Comment: I don't think there is an option for global. You have to do it by project wise

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47423124/2131576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually for now Rider contains the only one Web App Template - for net45. 
We are going to add another one - for net4.6.1 (or 4.6.2) in 2018.1. 
You can track status here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10888

The main issue here - we can not just change target framework version, but change all referenced package versions and some template files...

Answer (score 27):

This is one of the way to change the build framework in Rider. It allows you to switch the MSBuild version explicitly by selecting MSBuild.dll.

When you have multiple .NET framework, you can change it here.

This example is for .NET core project.

[image: Within settings]

In my system I installed latest .NET core RC after which Rider started complaining in older projects (when there were working fine prior to installation)

I had following versions

[image]

I selected the older version of MSBuild.dll and my project were back to normal.

Comment: Upvoted, this is the correct answer, why someone downvotes?

Comment: What a backwards way of changing the framework!  How's the user supposed to know the framework is tied to MSBuild?

Answer (score 17):

- in Rider IDE in solution explorer - right mouse click on the project,
- in properties (left pane) select Application (should be selected by default)
- in the right - change Target framework - click on ellipses, check your new framework
- Save

Comment: The easiest way! Thanks

Comment: I don't have ellipses here, only a dropdown with one old version that doesn't work. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

@FaizanRabbani You should have installed suitable .NET Developer Pack to change this option. You can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows